# "not supported on this architecture" error (git)

Tags: install

I'm trying to install the Gitx Git client on my friend's mac and it seems to install fine but when I run it I get the following error:

You cannot open the application "GitXStable" because it is not supported on this architecture.

Ideas?

Comment: It would be great if you tell us the Operating System and Mac’s model of your friend, our crystal balls are out of battery ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel application on a PowerPC Mac. Or vice versa. See if you can find an "Universal Binary" version of the application, which will run on either platform.

This link has a Universal Binary version: http://frim.frim.nl/GitXStable.app.zip

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [this version of GitX.](https://github.com/brotherbard/gitx) [Here](https://github.com/downloads/brotherbard/gitx/GitX%20Nov-17-2010.zip) is the direct link to download.
Supported architectures are **ppc7400, i386, x86_64.**